# GET request works in browser and Postman, but I get Unauthorized when using HttpClient and RestSharp

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I am issuing a request via Postman

"https://**APIKEY**:**PASSWORD**@**myexampledomain**.myshopify.com/**api/2021-04/custom_collections.json**"

and I get a true response:

```js
{
    "custom_collections": [
        {
            "id": 264277491901,
            "handle": "baran-kategori",
            "updated_at": "2021-04-08T18:05:03+03:00",
            "published_at": "2021-04-05T16:40:08+03:00",
            "sort_order": "best-selling",
            "template_suffix": "",
            "published_scope": "web",
            "title": "Baran Kategori",
            "body_html": ""
            
        },
        {
            "id": 264276377789,
            "handle": "category1",
            "updated_at": "2021-04-06T14:49:26+03:00",
            "published_at": "2021-04-05T16:12:36+03:00",
            "sort_order": "best-selling",
            "template_suffix": "",
            "published_scope": "web",
            "title": "Category1",
            "body_html": ""
            
        },
        {
            "id": 264362623165,
            "handle": "nike",
            "updated_at": "2021-04-08T18:05:03+03:00",
            "published_at": "2021-04-06T16:17:49+03:00",
            "sort_order": "best-selling",
            "template_suffix": "",
            "published_scope": "web",
            "title": "Nike",
            "body_html": ""
            
        }
    ]
}
```

when attempting to do the same GET through httpclient or restsharp, I am getting a 401 unauthorized.

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Thu, 08 Apr 2021 16:12:33 GMT
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Sorting-Hat-PodId: 188
  X-Sorting-Hat-ShopId: 56072536253
  Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  X-ShopId: 56072536253
  X-ShardId: 188
  WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm="Shopify API Authentication"
   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 89
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when attempting to do the same GET through httpclient or restsharp, I am getting a 401 unauthorized.

> WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm="Shopify API Authentication"

The HTTP 401 Unauthorized error indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

Please check if you provide the authentication credentials in the `Authorization` header field.

```
Authorization: Basic Your_base64EncodedAuthenticationString_Here
```